# How can I have a character separating line in TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I want to have a line between each character in a `TextView`.

**Can the original `TextView` do this? If not, how can I do it?**

[image]

Comment: you can with | symbol otherwise need to add View in between the TextView

Comment: you need to use separate TextView for all 0's see my answer

Answer (score 1):

**single textview will not be able to do that**. so

Try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="#000000" />
</LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext

```
      [![enter image description here][1]][1]
     <com.github.pinball83.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/masked_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:mask="*|*|*|*|*"
            app:notMaskedSymbol="*"
            app:maskIcon="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha"
            app:maskIconColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            />
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're populating your TextView from xml, you can do the following

```
android:text="Line1: \n Line2 \n Line3"
```

You can also specify the number of lines with `android:lines="2"`

Then you can separate them with **\n**

Additionally, you can do the following (when trying to update text from the code) :

```
String newText = "Line 1"
           + System.getProperty ("line.separator")
           + "Line 2"
           + System.getProperty ("line.separator");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:padding="3dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:background="@drawable/outline"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<View android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#353535"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<View android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#353535"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<View android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#353535"/>


<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<View android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#353535"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

> outline.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#353535" />
<padding android:left="2dp"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp" />
<corners android:radius="0dp" />
<solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

> Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

this might helps you